# Remove multiline comments from Notepad++ using regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have some SQL Code which has lot of comments e.g.

```
/*
This is 
my
multiline comment */
```

How can I remove them?

Comment: Be aware of edge cases like `$str = '/* blah'; some code; $str2 = '*/';` It becomes very hard. It's better to use a parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to Replace the following expression:

```
/\*.*?\*/
```

and make sure the '. matches newline' option is checked:

[image]

The breakdown of the regular expression:

- `/\*`: searches for the beginning of a comment; the `*` needs to be [escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15205536/4751173) with a backslash because otherwise it means '0 or more of the previous character'.
- `.*?`: the content of the comment; can be anything, but the `?` makes it 'non-greedy', i.e. it stops as soon as it can. This is important because otherwise two comment blocks would be found as one, including the non-comment text in between them.
- `\*/`: searches for the end of a comment; again, the `*` needs to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks a ton and specially thanks for the explanation as it helped me understand the answer better.